# How to install zbar shared libraries for linux

Tags: python, linux, zbar

On the doc: https://pypi.org/project/pyzbar/
The instructions are to use

```
sudo apt-get install libzbar0
```

which doesn't work. apt-get gives an error

```
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

so I use yum

libzbar0 doesn't exist, libzbar-dev doesn't exist, zbar doesn't exist.
The end goal is to do

```
pip install zbar
```

and I dont' get an error gcc exit status 1

Thanks

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the error that `apt` produced?

Comment: What is the error that apt gives you?

Comment: All Ubuntu `zbar` packages https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=zbar&searchon=names